# Is this power rule true for the natural base?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, maple

Two questions

1) I was wondering if $e^{k \ln{x}}=k$ for any k. Is it?
2)To test I went to Maple and typed `e^-ln(x)` and it gave $e^{-ln(x)}$. I tried simplify and it gave $x^{-ln e}$. How do you get Maple to simplify properly? Why doesn't it evaluate ln e = 1 ?

Comment: $e^{k \ln{x}}=x^k$, at least when $x$ is positive.  I don't use Maple, but you might try `exp(-log(x))` and see if that makes any difference

Answer (score 2):

To Maple "e" is just a letter, it does not recognise it as $e$.  Try "exp(-ln(x))".

Also (to make the point clear) try "evalf(e)" then "e:=exp(1)" and then "evalf(e)" again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true for any complex number k.

That's why Maple does the following simplification.

```
simplify( exp(k*ln(x)) );

                                  k
                                 x
```